# как работает reinterpret_cast

Tags: c++

Есть фрагмент кода. Почему в нем используется `reinterpret_cast` и как именно он работает? Почему тут не использовали `static_cast`?

```
ifstream is3("File3.txt", ios::binary);
if (is3)
{
    int value = 87;

    is3.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&value), sizeof(value));

    is3.close();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`static_cast` можно использовать для преобразования указателя типа `void *` в указатель типа `T *` или из указателя типа `T *` в указатель типа `void *`. `reinterpret_cast` предназначен для преобразования указателя из одного типа в другой тип, когда оба указателя не являются указателями типа `void *`

Из стандарта C++ (5.2.10 Reinterpret cast)

> 7 An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer
>   of a diﬀerent type.71 When a prvalue v of object pointer type is
>   converted to the object pointer type “pointer to cv T”, the result is
>   static_cast(static_cast(v)). Converting a prvalue of
>   type “pointer to T1” to the type “pointer to T2” (where T1 and T2 are
>   object types and where the alignment requirements of T2 are no
>   stricter than those of T1) and back to its original type yields the
>   original pointer value.

Для примера фрагмента кода из вашего вопроса это выглядело бы так с применением `static_cast`:

```
is3.read(static_cast<char*>(static_cast<void *>(&value)), sizeof(value));
```